# Doctrine one-to-many association with native and permanent filter criteria

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

Assume we have two entities and a bidirectional one-to-many association between them. At the inverse side the collection can get really huge, but most of the time only some specific subset of the association is needed based on a fixed criterion.

I know I can use extra-lazy loading of collections and criteria or filters as described in [chapter 8 of the Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). However, this only works if the entity manager is accessible, but I would like to have a solution that directly works on the entity level as discussed in [Ashley Dawson's blog](http://ashleydawson.co.uk/post/114044805548/doctrine-virtual-columns-part-1).

Let's say, we have the following simple object model with books and chapters

```php
class Book {
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "Chapter", mappedBy = "book" )
   * @var ArrayCollection
   */
  protected $chapters;

  /**
   * @return Chapter[]
   */
  public function getChapters() { /*...*/ }

  /**
   * @param Chapter $chapter
   */
  public function addChapter( Chapter $chapter ) { /*...*/ }

  /**
   * @param Chapter $chapter
   */
  public function removeChapter( Chapter $chapter ) { /*...*/ }
}

class Chapter {
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne( targetEntity = "Book", inversedBy = "chapters" )
   * @ORM\JoinColumn( name = "book_id", referencedColumnName="id" )
   * @var Book|null
   */
  protected $book;

  /**
   * @return Book|null
   */
  public function getBook() { /*...*/ }

  /**
   * @param Book|null $newBook
   */
  public function setBook( Book $newBook = null ) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Now, `Chapters` should be augmented by an attribute `important` and `Books` should get a second collection that only stores important chapters

```php
class Book {
  // ... as above ...

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany( targetEntity = "Chapter", mappedBy = "book" )
   * **HERE WE NEED TO SPECIFY SOME CRITERION FOR chapter.important = true**
   * @var ArrayCollection
   */
  protected $importantChapters;

  /**
   * @return Chapter[]
   */
  public function getImportantChapters() {
    return $this->importantChapters->toArray();
  }
}

class Chapter {
  // ... as above ...

  /**
   * @Column( type="boolean")
   * @var boolean
   */
  protected $important;
}
```

Is this in any way possible? The closest I got was to create a SQL view `important_chapters` on the database level that selects the correct rows from the table `chapters` and then create a new entity `ImportantChapter` on the Doctrine level. But I dislike this workaround, because it superficially creates a 3rd type of entity. Of course, one could push that solution forward and make `ImportantChapter` a child class of `Chapter`, use table inheritance and use `important` as the discriminator column. But this does not work in all cases, especially if the criterion becomes more complicated than in this toy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Doctrine Criteria without the entity manager also, as example:

```
  /**
   * @return Chapter[]
   */
  public function getImportantChapters() {
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('important', true));

    return $this->chapters->matching($criteria);
  }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes, indeed. Then I still have to figure out, how to extend the Criteria classes such that they supports the temporal and spatial extensions of PostgreSQL. Unfortunately, my criterion is not as simple as in the example.

Comment: I chose to combined your and my solution. Because the Docrine `Criteria` class does not provide the expressiveness I need for the selection, I created a view on top of the table that adds an additional column with boolean type